# Probability of drawing Rock Paper Scissors 13 times

Tags: probability

What are the odds of drawing 13 times in a row in Rock/Paper/Scissors?

Comment: Whatever $\left(\frac13\right)^{13}$ is.

Comment: Don’t own a scientific calculator and also unsure about converting to fractions. Can you help?

Comment: Try entering `(1/3)^13` into google.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you choose, there is a probability of $\frac{1}{3}$ that your friend does the same thing so the probability of a draw in a given round is $\frac{1}{3}$. Since each round is assumed to be independent, the probability is $$\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{13}\approx 6.27\cdot10^{-7}$$

or $1$ in $1,$$594$,$323$.

However, usually people employ strategy in rock paper scissors. For example, some people make their decision to be whatever your opponent last did, so independence wouldn't be present. There's a [Numberphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rudzYPHuewc) video on this.

Comment: What is that in terms of “ 1 in... “

Answer (score 1):

A game of rock, paper, scissors has three outcomes: winning, drawing, losing.

The probability of drawing one game is $\dfrac13$, so your required probability is $$\left(\frac13\right)^{13}=\frac1{3^8\cdot3^5}=\frac1{6561\cdot243}$$ and thus the odds of drawing $13$ times in a row is $1$ in $1594323$.

Comment: Any particular reason you split out $3^8$ and $3^5$?

Comment: No, I just find it easier to do $3^{13}$ by hand this way. The largest power of $3$ I can remember is $8$.

Comment: Gotcha. Strangely I know $3^{10} = 59049$ by memory but that's only because it's $9^5$; I played with a calculator when I was pre-kindergarten and remember calculating $9 \times \times \times \times ...$. Didn't do that with $3$ though, so I couldn't tell you $3^9$ by memory haha ...

Comment: I didn't know what a calculator was at that time ;)